# When does electron capture occur and when does positron emission occur?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

I’ve been told that [electron capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture) occurs when there isn’t enough energy to produce a positron by [beta plus decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission). Exactly why is this the case? Why does it take more energy for positron emission than electron capture?

Comment: I've added links that (I think) explain more clearly what you're asking. Please roll back me edit if I have got this wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electron capture:
$p+e^-\rightarrow n+\nu_e$
Beta plus decay:
$p\rightarrow n+e^++\bar{\nu_e}$

Let's check the masses of both sides of the processes:
Electron capture, initial state: $m_p+m_e=938.78 \frac{MeV}{c^2}$
Final state: $m_n=939.56 \frac{MeV}{c^2}$
The difference: (Final minus initial) $0.78 \frac{MeV}{c^2}$

Beta plus decay: (Positron emission)
Intial state: $m_p=938.27 \frac{MeV}{c^2}$
Final state: $m_n+m_e=940.07 \frac{MeV}{c^2}$
The difference: (Final minus initial) $1.8 \frac{MeV}{c^2}$

You see that you need to add more energy in order to do beta plus decay than to capture an electron.

Also note: A free proton can't emit a positron and turn into a neutron, but a free proton can capture an electron.

Answer (score 0):

A free proton can't emit a positron and turn into a neutron, but a free proton can capture an electron.

this is not true, EC only happens in many p's and many n's atoms.

but free p can only have positron emmision for a weak interaction, or the sun will burn too fast if it is done by EC {electron capture}

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE and thank you for the answer :) Consider taking the tour (help -> tour) and looking at the formatting tutorial here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting Have fun on the site :)

Comment: What does a free proton mean?